# Axios / Chrome: unexpected GET request after POST request

Tags: google-chrome, post, get, axios

I am converting text to audio. The idea is to send the text with a POST request and receive the audio as a file response to the same POST request. The back-end receives an unexpected GET request after the POST request. Axios code below:

```
    const response = await Axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: url,
        responseType: 'blob',
        data: {
            text: textContent
        }
    }).then(response => {
        const blob = new Blob([response.data], {type: 'audio/mpeg'});
        var blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        let a = new Audio(url)
        a.play()
    })
```

When I return the audio file to the GET request on the back-end, everything works as expected.

(1) Why do I receive a GET request after my POST request? Has this to do with Chrome's CORS?

(2) What is the best way to prevent it? I would like to send text and receive audio as a single atomic operation because I don't want to implement a database.

Comment: What is your `URL`? Does it have a trailing slash? What is your backend tech?

Comment: URL is http://127.0.0.1:8000/audio/data, I made sure that there is no trailing slash, back-end is Django

Answer (score 0):

When I created the audio file I should have used 'blobUrl' instead of 'blob':

```
let a = new Audio(blobUrl)
```

This line caused the unexpected GET request. It took me days to find this bug because I was totally focused on how Chrome handles CORS and how Django handles middleware and CORS headers.